# How to use SnakeYaml or YamlSlurper in an Android Gradle Groovy build script

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, yaml

I want to read a Yaml file in a Gradle Groovy script in my Android application during the build process. My script name is `script1.gradle`, and it is applied in `app/build.gradle` file. I run tasks from it in a console. The problem is that:

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper
```

does not work, my Groovy version is 3.0.17 (AGP 8.2.0)

I try to use:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
```

I add:

```
classpath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.2'
```

in my root `build.gradle` dependencies.

in : `app/build.gradle` I have:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
```

and it imports correctly.

Then I have:

```
apply from: 'script1.gradle'
```

but the error is only in script1.gradle:

```
  script '/Users/../MyApp/app/script1.gradle': 6: unable to resolve class org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
   @ line 6, column 1.
     import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
```

So, I understand that class path does not pass to my `script1.gradle` from the root scripts. Is my only choice to resolve this to turn my script into plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To use a library within a `build.gradle` script, declare the dependency in the `classpath` configuration within the `buildscript` block.

For example, you can do:

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.2'
    }
}

LoaderOptions options = new LoaderOptions()
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options)
String document = """
    - Hesperiidae
    - Papilionidae
    - Apatelodidae
    - Epiplemidae
"""
List<String> list = (List<String>) yaml.load(document)
println(list)
```

Run `./gradlew` and you will see printed:

```
[Hesperiidae, Papilionidae, Apatelodidae, Epiplemidae]
```

Comment: It didnt work for me, as I have written I have groovy code spread over multiple files. What worked for me was to add "implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.2'" to dependencies in buildSrc/build.gradle